Find the points on the ellipse given the 2 focal points and one point on the surface
I have two points $A=(x_a, y_a, z_a)$ and $B =(x_b, y_b, z_b)$ which are the focal points of a 2D ellipse. I also know that $C =(x_c, y_c, z_c)$ lies on the ellipse surface.
My goal is to find a few points (say, 10 points) sampled from the ellipse surface. I prefer it to have some form of uniform sampling, ie, I move along the ellipse surface and pick a point after some gap. (I can opt any other sampling as long as I am traversing through the entire ellipse surface).
Is it even possible to achieve this?
I know the equation of ellipse is
$$\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2} =1$$
Also, I am thinking I can find the equation of a plane  going through $A,B$ and $C$.
But, still I am unsure how to proceed. Can someone help me establish a closed form solution.

I meant the circumference. Sorry for the confusion

https://prog.lmu.edu.ng/colleges_CMS/document/books/GEC%20117%20Module%209-10%20%20Lecture%20Note%20(Repaired).pdf
